# How to zoom an item of a list on mouse-over, keeping it always visible (Flutter on Web platform)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

The problem is described like this.

In a web environment, I have to build a horizontal list of images (like in Netflix) which should increase the size of the element when the user positions the mouse cursor over them. To achieve this, I'm using a Stack (with `clipBehavior` equals to `Clip.none`) to render each item in the list, when I detect the mouse-over event I add a new Container (larger than the size of the original item) to draw an AnimatedContainer inside which will grow to fill it.

[image: Image 1, normal list]

The animation works great, but the container gets positioned down to the next right item on the list, however, I need it above the item.

[image: Overlapped image]

Here is the code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State {
      final double zoomTargetHeight = 320;
      final double zoomTargetWidth = 500;
      final double zoomOriginalHeight = 225;
      final double zoomOriginalWidth = 400;

      double _zoomHeight = 225;
      double _zoomWidth = 400;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?cars"),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          "List of items",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 235,
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return buildCard(index);
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return const SizedBox(
                                width: 12,
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: 10,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 200,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Map _showZoom = {};

      Widget buildCard(int index) {
        Stack stack = Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (event) {
                setState(() {
                  _showZoom["$index"] = true;
                });
              },
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                        "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=$index&cars"),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100),
                      height: zoomOriginalHeight,
                      width: zoomOriginalWidth,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (_showZoom["$index"] != null && _showZoom["$index"]!)
              Positioned(
                left: (zoomOriginalWidth - zoomTargetWidth) / 2,
                top: (zoomOriginalHeight - zoomTargetHeight) / 2,
                child: MouseRegion(
                  onHover: (_) {
                    setState(() {
                      _zoomHeight = zoomTargetHeight;
                      _zoomWidth = zoomTargetWidth;
                    });
                  },
                  onExit: (event) {
                    setState(() {
                      _showZoom["$index"] = false;
                      _zoomHeight = zoomOriginalHeight;
                      _zoomWidth = zoomOriginalWidth;
                    });
                  },
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: zoomTargetWidth,
                    height: zoomTargetHeight,
                    child: Center(
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),

                        width: _zoomWidth,
                        height: _zoomHeight,
                        // color: Colors.green.withAlpha(100),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=$index&cars"),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        );
        return stack;
      }
    }
```

Remember flutter config --enable-web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is precisely what you are looking for (Check also the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7191194789d1996c4ef864ccc0570eaf)):

[image: Screenshot]

The solution is:

1. Use an outer `Stack` that wraps the `ListView`;
2. Add another `ListView` in front of it in the `Stack` with the same number of items and same item sizes;
3. Then, ignore the pointer-events with [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) on this new `ListView` so the back one will receive the scroll/tap/click events;
4. Synchronize the scroll between the back `ListView` and the front one by listening to scroll events with `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>`;

**Here's the code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  final double zoomTargetHeight = 320;
  final double zoomTargetWidth = 500;
  final double zoomOriginalHeight = 225;
  final double zoomOriginalWidth = 400;

  late final ScrollController _controllerBack;
  late final ScrollController _controllerFront;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerBack = ScrollController();
    _controllerFront = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?cars"),
            Container(
              color: Colors.black87,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "List of items",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 225,
                      child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                        onNotification: (notification) {
                          _controllerFront.jumpTo(_controllerBack.offset);
                          return true;
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                          children: [
                            ListView.separated(
                              controller: _controllerBack,
                              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return buildBackCard(index);
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return const SizedBox(
                                  width: 12,
                                );
                              },
                              itemCount: 10,
                            ),
                            IgnorePointer(
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                controller: _controllerFront,
                                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return buildFrontCard(index);
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return const SizedBox(
                                    width: 12,
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: 10,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final Map _showZoom = {};

  Widget buildBackCard(int index) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (event) {
        setState(() {
          _showZoom["$index"] = true;
        });
      },
      onExit: (event) {
        setState(() {
          _showZoom["$index"] = false;
        });
      },
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.network(
              "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=$index&cars",
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100),
              height: zoomOriginalHeight,
              width: zoomOriginalWidth,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildFrontCard(int index) {
    Widget child;
    double scale;
    if (_showZoom["$index"] == null || !_showZoom["$index"]!) {
      scale = 1;
      child = SizedBox(
        height: zoomOriginalHeight,
        width: zoomOriginalWidth,
      );
    } else {
      scale = zoomTargetWidth / zoomOriginalWidth;
      child = Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: zoomOriginalHeight,
            width: zoomOriginalWidth,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                    "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=$index&cars"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return AnimatedScale(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      scale: scale,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great! thx u very much for sharing your knowledge, I was some progress but I was facing the issue that you mention about the scroll/tap/click events ...very tricky part

Comment: Hey @lepsch, I was digging more into your solution, but I found that I cannot use this approach because I need to trigger an action onTap ... and this doesn't allow me to do that (I put a GestureDetector over the Container but it doesn't work) ... what do you think I must do? In my approach, I manage to put an OverlayEntry into Overlay.of(context) ... but I have the same issue whit the scroll ... it seems to me a dead end ...

Comment: You're welcome! You should add the `GestureDetector` to the `BackCard`. The `FrontCard` will ignore everything indeed.

Comment: thx u are right, I tagged your answer as the correct one ... have a great day

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something different. Instead of Stacking the zoomed-out and zoomed-in images it could be just one image with a [`AnimatedScale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedScale-class.html) to do the transitions.

Check the code below:

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      AnimatedScale(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        scale: _showZoom["$index"] == true
            ? zoomTargetWidth / zoomOriginalWidth
            : 1,
        child: Image.network(
            "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=$index&cars"),
      ),
      if (_showZoom["$index"] == null || _showZoom["$index"] == false)
        Container(
          color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100),
          height: zoomOriginalHeight,
          width: zoomOriginalWidth,
        ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Check out the screenshot and the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ef186e5701d9400b804bd559af84c3c5):

[image: Screenshot]

**All source**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  final double zoomTargetHeight = 320;
  final double zoomTargetWidth = 500;
  final double zoomOriginalHeight = 225;
  final double zoomOriginalWidth = 400;

  double _zoomHeight = 225;
  double _zoomWidth = 400;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?cars"),
            Container(
              color: Colors.black87,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "List of items",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 235,
                      child: ListView.separated(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return buildCard(index);
                        },
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return const SizedBox(
                            width: 12,
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Map _showZoom = {};

  Widget buildCard(int index) {
    Stack stack = Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        MouseRegion(
          onEnter: (event) {
            setState(() {
              _showZoom["$index"] = true;
            });
          },
          onExit: (event) {
            setState(() {
              _showZoom["$index"] = false;
            });
          },
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AnimatedScale(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  scale: _showZoom["$index"] == true
                      ? zoomTargetWidth / zoomOriginalWidth
                      : 1,
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=$index&cars"),
                ),
                if (_showZoom["$index"] == null || _showZoom["$index"] == false)
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100),
                    height: zoomOriginalHeight,
                    width: zoomOriginalWidth,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    return stack;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the animation feels good, but it's not what I'm looking for